# Spring WebFlow, Validations and Models

Tags: spring-webflow

I am building a sample Spring WebFlow application and wanted to get some inputs on how the handle the below scenario.

I have 2 pages, the first page is a form where the user inputs data and the second page just displays the data the user entered in the previous page. The first page has a 'discard' and a 'continue' link and the second page just has the edit link which takes the user to the first screen so as to make edits on the data.

The scenario I am testing is..the user enters data, hits the continue link, the validators(Spring/WebFlow validators) are executed and the second page is displayed with the data (correct data). Now the user hits the edit link, changes a field on the first page, hits the continue link, the validators are executed and a error message(ex. user entered an invalid email address in the email field which is define as String in the model object) is shown on the same page (first page). Now the user hits the discard link and goes to the second page where the data is displayed. Now since the validations on the first page failed, the data displayed is not the correct one (shows the invalid email address).

Appreciate if some one can help me with displaying the old data (correct data) once the user hits the discard link since the data/model is not persisted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a view-state with a model and you take a transition with `bind="true"` (the default), the model object is changed for that snapshot. That is, once you "continue", you've updated the object.

I don't know if you could track and return the user to a previous snapshot. If not, you'd need to retain a "backup" object and manually restore that one in the code attached to "discard".